# relation between location of a sample mean in sampling distribution and the standard error

Tags: mathematical-statistics, distributions, sampling

Can
 someone explain the following statement with an example

**We'll describe the location of the sample mean by calculating how many standard errors it is away from the center of the sampling distribution. That will give us a z-score for our sample mean.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Z-scores for test results.** Suppose exam scores on a statewide math test are normally distributed
with mean $\mu = 300, \sigma =25.$ A particular student scores $X = 330,$ what is
her z-score?

$$Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{330 - 300}{25} = \frac{30}{25} = 1.2.$$

She scores 30 points above the mean $\mu,$ which is $30/25 = 1.2$ standard
deviations above the mean.

Suppose that last year's scores on an equivalent test were normally distributed
with $\mu = 305$ and $\sigma=27,$ and that her older brother scored $Y = 335.$ Is it
fair for him to brag that he's better at math than his sister? Aside from mentioning that
bragging is futile and maybe nasty, we could point out that his z-score was only
$(335 - 305)/27 = 30/27 = 1.11.$

One purpose of z-scores is to try to make
results from slightly different situations more comparable. If his sister
knows about z-scores, then he might decide to turn the conversation to one of his non-mathematical accomplishments.

**Z-scores for standard errors.** In your question you mention 'standard error'. That term is used
in statistical inference.  Suppose you have a sample of size $n = 100$ from a normal population with mean $\mu = 50$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 5$ (variance $\sigma^2 = 25).$ Also suppose
the sample mean is $\bar X = 50.8$

Then the 'standard error of the mean' is $\sigma_{\bar X} = SD(\bar X) = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{5}{10} = 0.5.$ If you want to know how many *standard errors* the sample mean $\bar X = 50.8$ is above the population mean $\mu = 50,$ then you use the same formula as for test scores above:
$Z =\frac{\bar X - \mu}{SD(\bar X)} = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{50.8-50}{0.5} = \frac{0.8}{0.5} = 1.6.$

So the sample mean is 1.6 *standard errors* above the population mean. In many applications, such a z-score often lies in the interval $(-2, 2)$ when nothing remarkable has occurred. But I should leave the specific applications to your text and lectures.

**Extra. *More on z-scores for test results:***

Another purpose of z-scores is to find various kinds of probabilities and proportions. We could use a printed table of the standard normal distribution to find the percentage of students who scored *lower* than the sister this year and the percentage who scored lower than her brother last year. These are called *percentiles.*

Maybe you can use
the printed standard normal cumulative distribution table in your textbook to find the percentiles shown below.
(I'm using R statistical software, but you should get similar percentiles, to about four significant digits, from the printed table.)

```
pnorm(1.2)
[1] 0.8849303     # sister's percentile is about 88.5
pnorm(1.11)
[1] 0.8665005     # brother's percentile is about 86.7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! This has been the best explanation to this question. I knew what is Z score and all this but now I know how it is used in real world.